# Energy gap of mean field model for transverse ising chain

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, eigenvalue, asymptotics, mean-field-theory

Polynomials of spin operators with real coefficients appear not infrequently in Hamiltonians and in mean field theory, and there are often tricks to find their eigenvalues.

For example, the polynomial $a S^x + b S^y + cS^z$ is unitarily equivalent to $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 +c^2} S^z$, which ensures that their eigenvalues match. Thus, for a spin-$S$ representation, $a S^x + b S^y + cS^z$ has eigenvalues $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 +c^2}S, \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 +c^2}(S-1), ...,  \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 +c^2}(-S)$.

In one version of mean field theory for the transverse field ising model, the quantity $$H_{MF} = -S\left(\left(\frac{S^z}{S}\right)^2 + g \frac{S^x}{S}\right)$$ yields the mean field Hamiltonian. Here, the $S^i$ are spin-operators transforming in the spin-$S$ representation. I am curious about the eigenvalues of $H_{MF}$. In particular, I want to know the leading asymptotic scaling of the gap between the first excited state and the ground state of this Hamiltonian.

In the usual $1d$ transverse field Ising model, there's a phase transition at $g=1/2$ that is signaled at finite system size $L$ through an exponential decay (as a function of $L$) of the gap for $g<1/2$, a polynomial decay of the gap for $g=1/2$, and an asymptotically constant gap for $g>1/2$.

In mean field theory, we expect the transition to occur at $g=1$. How does the gap close at $g=1$ as a function of $S$? I'm hopeful that there may be some trick like the one above or some systematic expansion in powers of $S$ that can investigate the gap's behavior accurately.